# Sync store with cookies in nuxtServerInit - NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using NuxtJS's auth module and trying to get the Bearer token and a custom cookie that contains a sessionType on nuxtServerInit so I can update the `store` with a `mutation`, but it only works when I reload the page.

If I close the browser and go directly to my app url, I keep getting undefined for auth._token.local because `nuxtServerInit` executes before the cookies are ready.

My code in store/index.js looks like this:

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch }, { req }) {
    // Parse cookies with cookie-universal-nuxt
    const token = this.$cookies.get('token')
    const sessionType = this.$cookies.get('sessionType')

   // Check if Cookie user and token exists to set them in 'auth'
    if (token && user) {
      commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', token)
      commit('auth/SET_SESSION_TYPE', user)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using nuxt-universal-cookies library.

What's the way to execute the action after the cookies are loaded on the browser?

Comment: what cookie library are you using?

Comment: I'm using nuxt-universal-cookies. 
Sorry, I've already edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having it work with F5 and not by hitting enter makes me suspect that it just works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, because `F5` and `Enter` should trigger same behaviour on Nuxt (apart from some cache headers).

The only suspicious thing about you code is the usage of an `async` function when the function is not returning or awaiting any promise.

So you either `await` for an `action`

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch }, { req }) {
    // Parse cookies with cookie-universal-nuxt
    const token = this.$cookies.get('token')
    const sessionType = this.$cookies.get('sessionType')

   // Check if Cookie user and token exists to set them in 'auth'
    if (token && user) {
      await dispatch('SET_SESSION', {token, user})
      //commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', token)
      //commit('auth/SET_SESSION_TYPE', user)
    }
  }
}
```

or you remove the async from the declaration

```
export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch }, { req }) {
    // Parse cookies with cookie-universal-nuxt
    const token = this.$cookies.get('token')
    const sessionType = this.$cookies.get('sessionType')

   // Check if Cookie user and token exists to set them in 'auth'
    if (token && user) {
      commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', token)
      commit('auth/SET_SESSION_TYPE', user)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and found out that `nuxtServerInit` is triggered first before the cookie was set like via a express middleware.